# pool.starmap() hangs on the first call (inside a likelihood sampler)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I am running an MC style chain, where the likelihood function (or cost function) should be trivially parallelizable since in each likelihood call it computes the average of 42 different objective function calls.

So the basic setup is like this

```
mypool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

def pred_per_obj(obj, x1):
    return obj.predict(x1)

def likelihood(x1, mypool, list_objs):
    xi_pred = mypool.starmap(pred_per_obj, zip(list_objs, repeat(x1)))
    return np.mean(xi_pred)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     MCsampler.sample(likelihood, priors)
```

Where I initiate a pool of workers, and for each likelihood call I want the workers to query the 42 objects (`list_obj`) in parallel. The objects are essentially 42 complex functions that I pickled and loaded as a list.

What is happening is that whenever I run this, it will spawn 4 processes, and start the first set of 4 `pred_per_obj()` calls, but then immediately hangs. Each process taking up some memory and CPU sitting at 0%.

What went wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you don't use main guard for making a `multiprocessing.Pool`, [terrible things will happen on Windows, macOS, and any other system not using `'fork'` as the default start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods). What OS are you running on, and what version of Python?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am running this in Linux and python 3.8.